# How to make users stay logged in after refreshing the app? using React Native Expo and Firebase

Tags: javascript, react-native, firebase-authentication, expo

How to make users stay logged in after refreshing the app? I found that AsyncStorage would only save user data but would not log in the user again.

im using Email and Password Authentication from Firebase.

```
const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();
const InsideStack = createNativeStackNavigator();

function InsideLayout(){
  return (
    <InsideStack.Navigator>
      <InsideStack.Screen name='My Todos' component={List}/>
      <InsideStack.Screen name='details' component={Details}/>
    </InsideStack.Navigator>
  )
}
export default function App() {
  const [user, setUser] = useState<User | null>(null);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

  const checkLocalUser = async () => {
    try {
      setLoading(true);
      const userInfo = await AsyncStorage.getItem('@user');
      const userData = userInfo ? JSON.parse(userInfo) : null;
      setUser(userData);
      console.log('Local User : ', userData );
    } catch(e){
      alert('Error' +e);
    }finally{
      setLoading(false);
    }
  }
  useEffect(() =>{
      checkLocalUser();
      const unsub = onAuthStateChanged(FIREBASE_AUTH, async (user)=>{
        
          console.log('user', user);
          setUser(user);
          await AsyncStorage.setItem('@user', JSON.stringify(user));
      
      });
      return () => unsub();

  },[])
  if(loading){
    return <ActivityIndicator size="large" color="#0000ff" />
  }
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName='Login'>
        {user ? 
          (<Stack.Screen name='Inside' component={InsideLayout} options={{headerShown: false}}/>) 
          : 
          (<Stack.Screen name='Login' component={Login} options={{headerShown: false}}/> )}
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

my List.tsx :

```
import { FIREBASE_AUTH } from '../../FirebaseConfig';
import {User} from 'firebase/auth';

interface RouterProps {
    navigation: NavigationProp<any, any>;
}

const List = ({navigation}: RouterProps) => {

    const user : User | null= FIREBASE_AUTH.currentUser;
  return (
    <View style={{flex:1, justifyContent:'center', alignItems:'center'}}>
        <Text>email : {user ? user.email : 'nothing'}</Text>
      <Button onPress={()=>{navigation.navigate('details')}} title="Open Details"/>
      <Button onPress={()=>FIREBASE_AUTH.signOut()} title="Logout"/>
    </View>
  )
}
```

If the user logs in, the email will display, but if the application is reloaded, the user's email will display "nothing"

Comment: Use `onAuthStateChanged` instead of `FIREBASE_AUTH.currentUser`.  You seem to be doing that in App but not in List for some reason.

Comment: Firebase automatically restores the user, but that takes some time. As Doug said, you'll want to use `onAuthStateChanged` in all components/screens to ensure you pick up when Firebase restores the user.

Comment: can i get some example?